# Magento- Can't load module on frontend

Tags: xml, magento

I'm trying to place the compare product block on my header top-link section, but with no success, beacuse any of my files are loaded in the frontend.
 
I have checked if the module is loaded in the admin section under advanced and if the path and config.xml exist(with alan storm extension), both the results are fine, but nothing appears in the header, even the css and js aren't loaded(I have cleaned the cache, no log files).
**File structure:**

```
app
    code
        community
            Razorphyn
                Minicompare
                    Block
                        View.php
                    etc
                        config.xml
    design
        frontend
            farmacia
                default
                    layout
                        minicompare.xml
                    template
                        minicompare
                            toplink.phtml
                            link.phtml
    etc
        modules
            Razorphyn_Minicompare.xml
skin
    frontend
        farmacia
            default
                css
                    razorphyn
                        minicompare.css
                js
                    razorphyn
                        minicompare.js
```

**Razorphyn_Minicompare.xml:**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Razorphyn_Minicompare>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Razorphyn_Minicompare>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**config.xml:**

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Razorphyn_Minicompare>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Razorphyn_Minicompare>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <minicompare>
        <class>Razorphyn_Minicompare_Block</class>
      </minicompare>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

**minicompare.xml:**

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/razorphyn/minicompare.js</name><params/></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/razorphyn/minicompare.css</stylesheet></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="header">
            <reference name="top.links">
                <block type="minicompare/view" name="minicompare_toplink" template="minicompare/toplink.phtml" >
                    <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" as="topcompare" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </reference>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the layout.xml definition to your module's config.xml

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <your_module>
                <file>path/to/layout.xml</file>
            </your_module>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add layout in config.xml

you can add below code below the .

```
<frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <razorphyn_minicompare>
                    <file>minicompare.xml</file>
                </razorphyn_minicompare>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
```

---